# How to NOT serialize default values

Tags: c#, json, azure

I can't help to look at my very empty pockets and wonder if there's any penny I could pinch in my web app.
Looking at the JSON I've been spitting out, I can't help to wonder if there's a way to NOT serialize default values, eg:

```
{
"gservs": {
  "EmpresaId": 1044,
  "GservsId": 7,
  "Descricao": "Cabelos"
},
"EmpresaId": 1044,
"ServicosId": 97,
"GServsId": 7,
"Descricao": "auxiliar geral",
"Informativo": "",
"simNao": false,
"PermiteEncaixe": false,
"UsaQuimica": false,
"CustosGerais": 0.0000,
"Preco": 0.0000,
"Comissao": 0.0000,
"ValPercComissao": "P",
"TipoComissao": false,
"ValPercCustos": "P",
"TipoCusto": false,
"ServicoAux": true,
"ValPercComisAux": "P",
"TipoComissaoAux": false,
"IncidComisAux": "A",
"DiasRetorno": 0,
"TempoExecucao": "00:00:00",
"TempoHora": 0,
"TempoMinMarcacao": 0,
"TempoHoraMarcacao": 0,
"TempoMin": 0,
"Ativo": false,
"Mobilidade": false,
"PermiteSimultaneidade": false,
"ParticipaMilhagem": true
}
```

If you check this out, you can count 406 bytes were wasted with default values. My estimate is that at the end of a regular day, I will have wasted about 1 dollar (I'm in Azure Zone 3 - Brazil South) with wasted bandwidth...

I learned a while back that I can tell JsonSerializer to ignore `null`s properties, so, can I do the same to "default" values as well?

Comment: JSON.Net has `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm

Comment: I agree with @phuzi but want to add that it wont work for booleans if you dont add [DefaultValue(false)]  above the bool property

Comment: How about compressing the response using something like GZIP compression?

Comment: Think twice about compressing. If the only thing you pay is bandwidth and you're fine with some milliseconds more latency it's a good solution.

But compressing is a CPU-intensive thing... In case you also have to pay for that.

Comment: @GauravMantri I've been looking out for it... so far, decrease in payload does not compensate for extra-CPU usage... I've been running on 80%+ regularly...

Comment: @Dominik you got my scenario figured out!

Comment: As @phuzi already said, try setting  DefaultValueHandling.Ignore. You can also modify the DefaultValue for a property. Means if you have a property double TaxPercentage you can set it with [DefaultValue(20.0)]. So the property wont be serialized when there's 20 in it.

Comment: @phuzi pls post your comment as answer! it worked as expected and I got up to 55% reduction on JSON size so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.net has a DefaultValueHandling enumeration to cope with different scenarios. Try something like

```
var serialiserSettings = 
    new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Then use this when serialising your objects to JSON. This will remove anything that has it's default value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
public class ThingToSerialize {
   [DefaultValue(false)]
   [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate)]
   public bool SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

This will not include SomeProperty in the output if its value is false.  When deserializing, if it is missing from the input, it will set the value to false.

Comment: this prob works but doing this on every property of every class will be a ton of work